# Getting Rectangular Coordinates to divide pdf page into two equal parts

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to divide a PDF page into two equal parts and add data into it. First I want to add data to first half fully then to the second one. The problem that I am having at present is that there is white-space left between contents of first paragraph and dividing line which I don’t want. I want contents to get shown fully.

Here is the sample code:

```
 new Rectangle(16, 36, 340, 806),
 new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, 806)
```

This is the Rectangular coordinates that I think is not accurate and giving this problem.
and this is the place where I am adding:

```
while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
{
    if (side_of_the_page == 0)
    {
        side_of_the_page = 1;
        canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
        canvas.LineTo(297.5f, 806);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, is to pre-render the complete column in simulation mode. Simulation mode means that no content is actually added to the page, but once you've rendered the column in simulation mode, you can ask the `ColumnText` for information about the `y`-position, about the number of lines that were rendered, and so on.

Based on this feedback, you can create a new column (you need to, because rendering in simulation mode *consumes* the content) and render it for real, taking into account the information you collected from the simulation.

Comment: OK Sir.Can i add COLOR in a specific line in an existing pdf file.If i see any ambiguity in the line..Actually sir this is the need that i am looking from long time to get answered.Does itextsharp provide any way to accomplish this.Please answer sir ...Thanks ..

Comment: That is a completely different question than the one you opened on this page. The rule on SO is not to use comments to ask additional questions, but to create a new question.